# How can I tell if my phone is locked?

Tags: sim-unlocking

Thanks to [a helpful commenter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50257/better-to-obtain-a-temporary-smartphone-in-the-us-or-in-europe#comment99745_50257) at a previous question, I now know that [Starting February 11, 2015, All Four Major US Carriers Will Let You SIM Unlock Your Phone](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/02/06/starting-february-11-2015-all-four-major-us-carriers-will-let-you-sim-unlock-your-phone-heres-the-fine-print/).

But that just raises another question: how do I know if my phone is locked in the first place? Is there some place in the phone's settings menu I can go to determine this, or do I have to get in touch with my carrier and check with their records?

Answer (score -1):

You could try putting another SIM card in your phone and see if it works, if it doesn't, it's locked.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I don't have access to working SIM cards not from my carrier. And the few people I know in the area where I am are all on the same as me.

Comment: What device do you have?